# Pandas merge 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying merge 2 dataframes.

```
df1
Date        A   B   C 
01.01.2021  1   8   14
02.01.2021  2   9   15
03.01.2021  3   10  16
04.01.2021  4   11  17
05.01.2021  5   12  18
06.01.2021  6   13  19
07.01.2021  7   14  20
```

```
df2 
Date         B
07.01.2021  14
08.01.2021  27
09.01.2021  28
10.01.2021  29
11.01.2021  30
12.01.2021  31
13.01.2021  32
```

Both dataframes have one same row (although there could be several overlappings).
So I want to get df3 that looks as follows:

```
df3 
Date        A   B   C
01.01.2021  1   8   14
02.01.2021  2   9   15
03.01.2021  3   10  16
04.01.2021  4   11  17
05.01.2021  5   12  18
06.01.2021  6   13  19
07.01.2021  7   14  20
08.01.2021  Nan 27  Nan
09.01.2021  Nan 28  Nan
10.01.2021  Nan 29  Nan
11.01.2021  Nan 30  Nan
12.01.2021  Nan 31  Nan
13.01.2021  Nan 32  Nan
```

I've tried
`df3=df1.merge(df2, on='Date', how='outer')` but it gives extra A,B,C columns. Could you give some idea how to get df3?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are rather looking for a concatenation or update. Check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) on merge, concat and update.

Comment: are you looking for `df2.update(df1)`

Comment: @Chris I've made a mistake. It is about concat but still i get  2 rows of  `07.01.2021  7   14  20`in df3

Answer (score 1):

[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) outer without specifying `on` (default `on` is the intersection of columns between the two DataFrames in this case `['Date', 'B']`):

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer')
```

`df3`:

```
          Date    A   B     C
0   01.01.2021  1.0   8  14.0
1   02.01.2021  2.0   9  15.0
2   03.01.2021  3.0  10  16.0
3   04.01.2021  4.0  11  17.0
4   05.01.2021  5.0  12  18.0
5   06.01.2021  6.0  13  19.0
6   07.01.2021  7.0  14  20.0
7   08.01.2021  NaN  27   NaN
8   09.01.2021  NaN  28   NaN
9   10.01.2021  NaN  29   NaN
10  11.01.2021  NaN  30   NaN
11  12.01.2021  NaN  31   NaN
12  13.01.2021  NaN  32   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always want to keep the first full version, you can concat the df2 on the end of df1 and drop duplicates on the Date column.

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(subset='Date')
```

Output

```
    Date    A   B     C
0  01.01.2021  1.0   8  14.0
1  02.01.2021  2.0   9  15.0
2  03.01.2021  3.0  10  16.0
3  04.01.2021  4.0  11  17.0
4  05.01.2021  5.0  12  18.0
5  06.01.2021  6.0  13  19.0
6  07.01.2021  7.0  14  20.0
1  08.01.2021  NaN  27   NaN
2  09.01.2021  NaN  28   NaN
3  10.01.2021  NaN  29   NaN
4  11.01.2021  NaN  30   NaN
5  12.01.2021  NaN  31   NaN
6  13.01.2021  NaN  32   NaN
```